# sonar-maven-plugin with multi-module maven

Tags: maven, sonarqube, owasp, sonarqube5.1

I have a multi-module maven project which seems to have correctly generated OWASP dependency reports at both the parent and child module /target dirs using the org.owasp:dependency-check-maven plugin as so:

[image: dependency-check-report generation]

However, referencing the plugin [docs](https://github.com/stevespringett/dependency-check-sonar-plugin), and executing the sonar-maven-plugin as below, I just can't work out what the correct command should be, any combination seems to lead to a build failure:

> mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.sources=? -Dsonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=?

Can anyone explain how to configure a multi-module maven project and have Sonar recognise the OWASP dependency reports?

Below is a screenshot of the starting point - we've had a CI pipeline up and running producing separate unit and integration test coverage stats for each of the submodules for some time.

[image: current sonar view]

Comment: I would start with a simple analysis (without the dependency reports). Get that working, then add the dependency reports back in.

Comment: Thanks @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam, our CI pipeline has been up and running for some time, producing separate unit and integration test etc coverage for each submodule. Have added a screenshot to the main question for reference. Kind regards, Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so have contacted the author and the [dependency-check-sonar-plugin](https://github.com/stevespringett/dependency-check-sonar-plugin) doesn't work with a multi-module maven project.

So we are just going to produce a static artefact in a one-off fashion and not attempt to integrate with our CI pipeline.